# How can I download XP SP3 to install on a different computer?

Tags: windows, download, sp3, installer

The Microsoft support page just says to enable automatic updates, but I've got broadband and my friend who's machine I'm repairing has a very slow connection.

Can I download it here and take over an `.exe` or something on a thumb drive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a [direct download to Windows XP SP3 offline install](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5b33b5a8-5e76-401f-be08-1e1555d4f3d4&displaylang=en).

For your information, it is 316.4MB

> #### Overview
>
> Windows XP Service Pack 3
> (SP3) includes all previously released
> updates for the operating system. This
> update also includes a small number of
> new functionalities, which do not
> significantly change customers’
> experience with the operating system.
> If you're updating just one computer,
> please visit Windows Update at
> http://update.microsoft.com.
>
> #### Note:
>
> Customers running Microsoft
> Dynamics Retail Management System
> (RMS) are advised to install a hotfix
> for a Microsoft Dynamics RMS issue
> prior to installing Windows XP SP3.
>
> #### DO NOT CLICK DOWNLOAD IF YOU ARE
>
> UPDATING JUST ONE COMPUTER:
> A smaller,
> more appropriate download is now
> available on Windows Update. The best
> way to ensure you get Windows XP
> Service Pack 3 is by turning on the
> Automatic Updates feature in Windows
> XP. You can use our step-by-step
> instructions or, if you prefer, let us
> do it for you.
>
> The Microsoft Download Center site is
> your only authorized web source for
> downloading a licensed copy of Windows
> XP Service Pack 3. To report a website
> offering unlicensed copies of Windows
> XP SP3 for download, please send
> e-mail to: piracy@microsoft.com or
> visit
> http://www.microsoft.com/piracy/ReportingUs.mspx.

Comment: But if I recall correctly, it requires service pack 2 to be installed prior

Comment: nope, this one includes all prior service packs and can be installed on any previous version of XP.  from the link: "Supported Operating Systems: Windows XP Home Edition ; Windows XP Professional Edition ; Windows XP Service Pack 1; Windows XP Service Pack 2"

Comment: which is why it's 300+MB.

Comment: "To install SP3, either Windows XP Service Pack 1a (SP1a) or Windows XP Service Pack 2 (SP2) must already be installed." http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/windowsxp/sp3/default.mspx

Comment: @DavidPearce is correct. The service pack throws an error of "Setup has detected that the version of the Service Pack
installed on your system is lower than what is necessary to apply this hotfix. At minimum, you must have Service Pack 1 installed."

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/42977/how-to-avoid-windows-genuine-advantage-for-an-xp-update/42986#42986) to my question gives a link to a DIY solution where you can download patches offline (even from a linux machine if you wish).